# No puedo respaldar con python una bd postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

disculpen, tengo una duda.
Al intentar respaldar me arroja un error en navegador de

[WinError 123] El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos: 'D:\Documentos\GitHub\app\backup_2021-11-30_09:56:10.backup'

Y en mi terminal donde corro el servidor el error de:

"pg_dump" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Muestro mi codigo:

```
def create_backup_postgresql(self):
        file = ''
        data = {}
        try:
            db_name = connection.settings_dict['NAME']
            data_now = '{0:%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.now())
            name_backup = "{}_{}.backup".format('backup', data_now)
            script = 'pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "{}" {}'.format(name_backup, db_name)
            subprocess.call(script, shell=True)
            file = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, name_backup)
            db = DatabaseBackups()
            db.user = self.request.user
            db.archive.save(name_backup, File(open(file, 'rb')), save=False)
            db.save()
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        finally:
            if len(file):
                os.remove(file)
        return data
```

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        action = request.POST['action']
        try:
            if action == 'add':
                db_type = connection.vendor
                if db_type == 'sqlite':
                    data = self.create_backup_sqlite()
                elif db_type == 'postgresql':
                    data = self.create_backup_postgresql()
                else:
                    data['error'] = 'No se ha podido sacar el respaldo de la base de datos {}'.format(db_type)
            else:
                data['error'] = 'No ha seleccionado ninguna opción'
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

¿Alguna sugerencia amigos?
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

intestaste cambiar las barras invertidas() por las inclinadas(/) ?
Se genero un post sobre un problema similar al tuyo hace un tiempo, **la solución fue que los dos puntos no están permitidos en los nombres de archivo de Windows.:**

- Documentación [Nombrar Archivos, Rutas de Acceso, etc](https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- Link Debate [discusión del problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115580/python-os-rename-oserror-winerror-123)

Comment: Ya eliminé los dos puntos, pero aun así al parecer el problema viene de mas atrás con el error: "pg_dump" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.